# How to retrieve textbox value in a controller which is supplied with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to pass value of text box to my controller, i can pass that but i cant retrieve it at controller. Help me to identify my mistake.

Form.php (dept_name is a id of my textbox)

```
<script>   
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#submitbutton").click(function(e) { 
                            var deptname=$('#dept_name').val();                           
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://localhost/finalProjectWork/admin_department_controller/adddept/',
                                type: 'POST',
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'},
                                data: {name:deptname},
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                success: function(test) {
                                    alert(test);

                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    alert("Already Exists");
                                }
                            });
                            e.preventDefault(); 
                        });
                    });</script>
```

controller :

```
 public function adddept()
    {
        $deptname=$this->input->post('name');

        $this->load->model('admin_department_model');
        $this->admin_department_model->insertdept($deptname);
        echo "Successfully inserted";
    }
```

Comment: try this in your controller, and see data is coming : `print_r($_POST);exit;`

Comment: are you accept index.php  if u did you have to change ajax url http://localhost/finalProjectWork/index.php/admin_department_controller/adddept/

Comment: no it gives me array(). i mean blank array

Comment: try to alert it within your js first are you getting value over there.

Comment: not an issue with url

Comment: yes its give me a proper output in js i had tried alert(deptname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>   
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#submitbutton").click(function(e) { 
                            var deptname=$('#dept_name').val();                           
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://localhost/finalProjectWork/admin_department_controller/adddept/',
                                type: 'POST',
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'},
                                data: {name:deptname},
                                success: function(test) {
                                    alert(test);

                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    alert("Already Exists");
                                }
                            });
                            e.preventDefault(); 
                        });
                    });</script>
```